# in twig how to print out keys and values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I just can't seem to find the right twig code to simply print out values from an array.

I have an array which contains the applied filters to a page.

I can dump the array by doing `{{ dump(filters) }}`

This dumps the array like this:

> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["colour"]=> string(5) "White" } [1]=> array(1) { ["colour"]=> string(3) "Red" } [2]=> array(1) { ["country"]=> string(6) "France" } }

Which shows I have 3 filters applied. `colour=red`, `colour=white` and `country=france`.

All I want to do is for every element in filters print these to the page like so.

colour:Red colour:White country:France.

I can then turn them into links that will remove the filter.

The code I have so far is

```
{% if filters is iterable %}
        {% for elem in filters %}
            {{ ?????????? }}:{{ ?????????? }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Most things I try errors, or complains I am converting arrays to strings

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filters variable is an array of arrays, so you need to do something like:

```
{% for filter in filters %}
    {% for key, value in filter %}
        {{ key }} : {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos but all i get when I do this is errors regarding converting arrays to string.

Comment: Scrap that last comment, this actually works for me now. Thanks Carlos. I thought I was going to have to do some kind of conversion to string.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
{% for key,value in filters %}
   {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wish I could, that just complains about array to string conversion for 'key' and throws exeptions for value